# Weird boolean evaluation behaviour in PHP

Tags: php, boolean, boolean-logic

Let me share some PHP code with you:

```
$var1 = '';

$var2 = 0;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($var1 == $var2); //prints bool(true)
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($var1 != $var2); //prints bool(false)
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(!$var1 == $var2); //prints bool(false)
echo '</pre>';

echo '---<br />';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($var1 === $var2); //prints bool(false)
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($var1 !== $var2); //prints bool(true)
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(!$var1 === $var2); //prints bool(false) .. WTFF????
echo '</pre>';
```

Question is... why does that last statement `(! $var1 === $var2)` **NOT** yield the same result as `($var !== $var2)` ??? I mean, it's what we would expect, no?

I used to use both ways interchangeably but now I only use `!==` although I still don't know why the other form does not work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!$var1` is `TRUE`, `$var2`is `0`.

They are not equal, so the result is `false`.

Maybe you were confused with `!($var1 === $var2)`

Answer (score 1):

The last statement is evaluated as:

```
(!$var1) === $var2
```

Since `$var1` is a falsey value (empty string), inverting it gives you a truthy value (`1`), which is not equal (and certainly not identical!) to `0`. Thus, the comparison is `false`.

(Note that I'm deliberately using the terms "truthy" and "falsey" here, as `''` and `0` are not quite `true` and `false`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

The not operator is first applied to `$var1` and results in a *boolean true*. And a *boolean true* is not exact equal to a *int 0*, so it evaluates to false.